# Is there an RxJS operator similar to withLatestFrom but with a parameter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

My Angular 5 application is based on [NgRx](https://ngrx.github.io/), a state management library similar to Redux but based on RxJS.

I often need to get the latest value from the store based on the payload of the current action.

In RxJS terminology, it means that I have my main stream that constantly produce items and for each new item I need to create a side stream based on the item's value, get the latest value from this stream, and combine it with the main stream.

At the moment, I do something like this:

```
@Effect()
public moveCursor$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR),
  switchMap(action => this.store$.select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId)).pipe(
    first(),
    map(table => ({action, table}))
  )),
  map(({action, table}) => {
    ...
  })
)
```

I know it is probably not the best solution and I am looking for something like this (which is not possible with `withLatestFrom` operator):

```
@Effect()
public moveCursor$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR),
  withLatestFrom(action => this.store$.select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId))),
  map(([action, table]) => {
    ...
  })
)
```

So my question is: Is there any RxJS operator which is similar to `withLatestFrom` which can take a value produced by the first stream as a parameter?

Answer (score 7):

I finally did it...

```
doEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<someAction>(losActionTypes.someAction),
    switchMap/mergeMap/concatMap(    // according to your logic
    action => of(action).pipe(
       withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(leFancySelector)))
    )),
    tap(console.log)    // tap if you don't believe me
```

Comment: This avoids the `first()` or `take(1)`, but overall I don't think it's any more readable than OP's current solution, and doesn't offer a single operator that does what is asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mergeMap` and `map` to combine the action with the table selected from the store:

```ts
@Effect()
public moveCursor$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR),
  mergeMap(action => this.store$
    .select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId))
    .pipe(
      first(),
      map(table => [action, table])
    )
  ),
  map(([action, table]) => {
    ...
  })
)
```

And you'd need to use `first` - or `take(1)` - to ensure that the inner observable selected from the store emits only a single value - the table that's to be combined with the action.

Comment: Thanks. But would not it start producing new values even if no new action is dispatched but the value of the table in the store has changed?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would. You'd need to use `first` or `take(1)`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late and you've already solved this, but...

Firstly I cant clearly see what you're trying to achieve here. What is your intented behavior?

*only when your `TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR` is called and with the latest value from your store*

or

*when your `TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR` is called or latest value from your store is updated*

---

If it is *only when your `TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR` is called and with the latest value from your store*, using just the `withLatestFrom` should be good enough

```
@Effect()
public moveCursor$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR),
  withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId))),
  map(([action, table]) => {
    ...
  })
)
```

---

If its is *when your *`TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR` is called or latest value from your store is updated* then i would use a mergeMap to combine your *Actions Observable* and your *Latest value from the store*

```
//Actions Observable
this.actions$.pipe(ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR))

//Latest Value from the store
this.store$.select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId))

//Result:
@Effect()
public moveCursor$: Observable<Action> = mergeMap([
  this.actions$.pipe(ofType<TableAction.MoveCursor>(TableActionType.MOVE_CURSOR)), 
  this.store$.select(selectTableById(action.payload.cursor.tableId))
]).map(({action, table}) => {
  ...
});
```

But beware, this will cause the effect to run *EVERY* time the selector is updated.(which should be okay assuming your tableId is a memoized.

Answer (score -1):

No, as of rxjs 6 I don't believe there is such a built-in operator. I think your current solution is the most straightforward way to do it, I'm using that pattern as well, and it's important to remember to include the `first()` or `take(1)` to avoid responding to subsequent emissions of the selector.